# Alter A Partitioned Table Column DataType

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

My existing database is on SQL Server 2005 - Version 9.0.5000. Migrating to SQL Server 2008 R2

We have a huge table of 500+ million rows of data. A column `PriceListDate` is defined as `varchar(8)` and is part of the composite primary key. To make matters worse, the table is partitioned on this column.

Since there is an opportunity now to remodel the DB, I am contemplating on changing the datatype to `integer` for this column. However, there seems to be no easy way of doing this, but to create another table with the new datatype, migrate the data and then delete the old table and partition scheme and function.

Any pointers on what to watch for with this approach? Or is there an alternate, better approach?

Raj

Comment: Why wouldn't you convert the date to a date type? There's a lot of support for doing date calculations, such as the datediff function, when the column is a date, datetime, etc. What problem is there with the current setup? Is this database a data warehouse (where dates represented as integers are more common)?

Comment: @MichaelHarmon Changing data type of a primary (and my guess is clistered index) will require tempdb size to be of 1-2 table sizes + it will be logged: even minimal logging wil take a lot of space.

Comment: What is the size of the table, are there any other changes to this table planned?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts:

If you leave as it is you can have this old table as a history table, create another table with new layoyut for new data and create a view and/or SP to access both of them or the one needed.

If decide to change the data type:
 - Since the process should be controllable, it should be done in batches anyway
 - It would be good to leverage existing partitioning.

My the solultion would be:
Set 3 tables: Old_Big_Table, Temp_table (with old structure, indexes, partitioning) and New_Table (with new structure, on a different partition scheme and function)

For Each partition:

1. Switch 1 partition to Temp_table
2. Drop indexes
3. Change data type
4. Create indexes as per new layout on new PS and PF
5. Switch partition to New_table
6. Drop new indexes on Temp_table
7. Create old indexes on Temp_table on old PS and PF
8. Optional: log result of this iteration to Log_table

In Step 7 is not strictly necessary to create old index on any PS and PF. As lond as structure of indexes is the same it will suffice.